# How intimate can a married couple be in public?

Tags: nikah, practical-islam, husband-wife, love, modesty

Can a husband and wife walk together holding hands in the park for example or is that already too much? Does it depend when you are in a non Muslim or Muslim country and what is the 'Urf - custom? If she is at the airport and the husband is leaving her to fly what can they do in public when saying goodbye to each other? Hug?

Answer (score -1):

**Asalaam Alaikum,** 
These are *cultural* values and should not be confused with the *deen*. As long as you do not break the social rules of a country, just make sure your attire is appropriate, as ordered by Allah and covers you. Other than that, maintain modesty, self respect and then hugs, kisses and holding hands should be fine :)

Comment: No, no, this is incorrect, in the deen there is a level of intimacy you should keep low when you are not completely alone.